# How to ignore all files, but not directories in Git

Tags: git

I want to ignore all the files present in current directory, but want to track all the directories and sub directories.

How can I do that?

Adding `*` in `.gitignore` simply ignores everything, including directories and sub-directories. How to ignore only files, but not directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
/*
# Except for directories
!/*/
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add an exclude section below with `*/*`